# select indexOfObject from NSArray in Xcode by comparing string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Hi I have `NSarray` values in Xcode. I need to get array  indexOfObject by comparing string values.
my array values are

```
 (
    {
    firstName = lord;
    lastname = krishna;
    },
    {
    firstName = priya;
    lastname = amirtha;
    }
 )
```

If I type first name in textfield and click button means last name want to display in another textfield.
   thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far? What did it do wrong?

Comment: There is this neat invention called a `for` loop.  It really works!!  You should try it some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the title of your question:

```
NSString *compareString = @"something";
NSMutableArray *indexesOfMatches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSString *string in theArray) {

   if ([string isEqualToString:compareString]) {
       NSNumber *index = [[NSNumber numberWithInterger:[theArray indexOfObject:string]];
       [indexOfMatches addObject:index];
    }
}
    //indexOfMatches will now contain NSNumber objects that represent the indexes of each of the matching string objects in the array
```

I think that using an NSDictionary would be better for you though. Then you can simply keep the first and last names as Key Value pairs.

```
NSDictionary *names = @{@"lord" : @"krishna", @"priya" : @"amirtha" };
```

Then you can just do value for key when you get the first name:

```
NSString *firstName = @"lord";
NSString *lastName = [names valueForKey:firstName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Store **firstNameArray** and **lastNameArray** a mutable array `NSMutableArray`.

Using `Fast Enumeration`. Suppose **array** is the array you are provided with

```
for (NSDictionary *item in array) {
        [firstNameArray addObject:[item objectForKey:@"firstName"]];
        [lastNameArray addObject:[item objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
    }
```

After entering the data in `firstNameTextField` click the **button**

Button action method implementation

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {
  NSInteger index = [firstName indexOfObject:[firstNameTextField text]];
  [lastNameTextField setText:[lastName objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

Comment: where to get array name.

Comment: Edited the answer. please check

Comment: Is the answer is what you want?